# how POST and save data from form to rest api in JSON format using ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, api

I have a form which should post and saves data node_id, latitude, longitude, and location data to rest API (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/node/) using jquery ajax :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- leaflet css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
crossorigin=""/>
<!--leaflet js after leaflet css-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
crossorigin=""></script>

    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- kode form -->
      <form class="form" id="myForm">
        <h2>Add Node</h2>
        <label for="node_id">Node Id :</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="node_id" id="node_id" style="width: 10%;"></br></br>
    <h5>Get the latitude and longitude of the node</h5>
    <label for="latitude">Latitude : </label>
    <label name="latitude" id="latitude"></label></br>
    <label for="longitude">Longitude : </label>
    <label name="longitude" id="longitude"></label></br>
    <style>     /*map code*/
        #node1Map {
        height: 350px; }
      </style>
      <div id="node1Map"></div>
    <script>
    const mymap = L.map('node1Map').setView([-7.286190082778849, 109.52270507812501], 8);
    const attribution ='&copy: <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

    const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, { attribution });
    tiles.addTo(mymap);

// get coordinate
var lat, long, marker;
mymap.on('click', function(e) {
if(marker) mymap.removeLayer(marker);
lat = e.latlng.lat;
long = e.latlng.lng;
console.log('lat', lat);
console.log('long', long);
marker = L.marker([lat, long]).addTo(mymap);
document.getElementById('latitude').textContent = lat;
document.getElementById('longitude').textContent = long;
});
</script></br>

<label for="location">Location Address :</label></br>
<input type="text" name="location" id="location" style="width: 100%;"></br></br>     
<div class="btn-block">
<button id="submit-data">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>

<!--JQUERY DATA-->
<script>
$(function (){
    var $node_id = $('#node_id');
    var $latitude = $('#latitude');
    var $longitude = $('#longitude');
    var $location = $('#location');

    $('#submit-data').on('click', function() {
        var data = {
            node_id: $node_id.val(),
            latitude: $latitude.val(),
            longitude: $longitude.val(),
            location: $location.val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '127.0.0.1:8000/api/node/',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>

    </div>
    <!-- end of page content (container-fluid) -->

  </div>
  <!-- End of Main Content -->

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
    <div class="container my-auto">
      <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
        <span>Copyright &copy; GMLEWS 2019</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- End of Footer -->

</div>
<!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- End of Page Wrapper -->

<!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
<a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>



<style>
html, body {
min-height: 100%;
}
body, div, form, input, select { 
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
outline: none;
}
form {
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ccc; 
}
input {
width: calc(100% - 10px);
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 3px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
input:hover, textarea:hover, select:hover {
outline: none;
border: 1px solid #095484;
}
.name input {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
option {
background: #fff;
}
.btn-block {
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
button {
width: 150px;
padding: 10px;
border: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
border-radius: 5px; 
background-color: #095484;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
background-color: #0666a3;
}
@media (min-width: 568px) {
.name {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.name input {
width: 47%;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
}
</style>

{% endblock content %}
```

The API is look like this :

```
[
{
    "node_id": 1,
    "latitude": "123",
    "longitude": "123",
    "location": "dimana"
},
{
    "node_id": 2,
    "latitude": "123",
    "longitude": "124",
    "location": "dimana"
}
]
```

I try to add node_id:3 from the form, but it doesn't post/save to the API. Can someone help me? Why this is happen?

Comment: Check your dev tools, what kind of error or status codes are being thrown?

Comment: there is no errors. It just don't post or create status:201

Comment: If there's nothing even showing up in the network tab, how do you know you're even calling the method? Time to debug your JS

Comment: Hello,

Use `event.preventDefault()` or `<button type="button" id="submit-data">Submit</button>` to check your response. Currently you are not able to see your response(success or error) because submit button will  'reset' or 'submit' the form which causes page reload

Comment: To add to what kokila said you can also check "Preserve Log" in Chromes dev tools to prevent losing info on page loads and refreshes